# Как пробросить cnt из дочернего компонента родителю в render react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю подсветку dom элементов по поиску. Render подсвченных элементов взял из плагина (код ниже), работает норм, но как теперь вывести их количество в родительском компоненте? Пробовал через родительскокую callback фнукцию showCnt пробросить, но в render ее нельзя вызвать,а в componentDidUpdate  работает с запозданием.

```
  cnt:[],

render: function () {

    var p = this.props,
        highlightStart = p.string.search(p.highlight);

    if (!p.highlight || highlightStart === -1) {
        return h('span', null, p.string);
    }
    var highlightLength = p.highlight.source.length,
        highlightString = p.string.substr(highlightStart, highlightLength);

    this.cnt.push(highlightString);
    this.props.showCnt(this.cnt.lenght);
    return (
        h('span', null,
            p.string.split(p.highlight).map(function (part, index) {
                return h('span', { key: index },
                    index > 0 ?
                        h('span', { className: 'json-inspector__hl' }, highlightString) :
                        null,
                    part);
            }))
    )

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

В родительском компоненте создайте состояние и передайте его в рендер функцию. В рендер функции в коде найдите определение количества найденных элементов и обновляйте состояние подредактировав код рендера.

Comment: так кол эл в рендере дочернего компонента

Comment: @KirillDanilenko кол что? В общем, в реакте вам надо поднять общий state до ближайшего общего родителя. В реакте нельзя пробрасывать что-то наверх просто так.